# Is possible to transfer files with FTP?

Tags: drush

I connected to a site using SSH with Drush. Is there a way to use FTP with Drush?

Answer (score 6):

Drush does not have a built-in wrapper for ftp / sftp, but you can do the same operation using rsync.  If you have rsync, setup your [drush aliases](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) for it. You can then copy the code and (upload) files for the site via:

`drush rsync @mysite.dev @mysite.live`

You can copy just the (upload) files via:

`drush rsync @mysite.dev:%files @mysite.live:%files`

This will use the same credentials that you already set up to use ssh with Drush.